# Gravity does not work in multi languages

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, gravity

This is my `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnAgree"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/label_gdpr_agree"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/yellow_gdpr_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvGdprPage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
```

The problem is that it works well in `English`, but not `Vietnamese`. In `Vietnamese` lang, it's only center horizontal (top center). Does anyone have this issue? Below image is in `Vietnamese`.

[image]

Comment: @MartinZeitler `Vietnamese` is not a  RTL language

Comment: @VicJordan ever tried `layout_width="wrap_content"` or `layout_width="match_parent"`?

Comment: Could you please post complete layout code and other relevant code as well so that we can debug it easily.

Comment: A screenshot of what's happening (working in English, not working in Vietnamese) would also help. Do you have locale-specific layouts?

Comment: It may be the `layout_width`. set `layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: @VicJordan I need it to match_parent with some margins,  so I cannot use it.

Comment: @TedHopp I did upload a `screenshot`.  I have a `values-vi` folder for strings only.

Comment: Try to change android:textAlignment attribute to "gravity", this attribute will force the TextView layout the text use the gravity you specified

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc  try android:includeFontPadding="false" , it should help

Comment: @AbdulSamad it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 'Relative layout' as parent layout.Then use alignParentEnd properties to support rtl.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnAgree"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="@string/label_gdpr_agree"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp100"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why `RelativeLayout`? OP is using `ConstraintLayout` and there must be solution with `ConstraintLayout` as well.

Comment: For me 'Relative layout' is best approach. So i suggested to use it.

Comment: No, I will stick with ConstraintLayout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't trace why you are getting such an issue.

The code mentioned below is written by me and works absolutely fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnAgreeEnglish"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="This is my text. This is my text."
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnAgreeVietnamese"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Đây là văn bản của tôi. Đây là văn bản của tôi."
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnAgreeEnglish"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope, this helps you but if you still face any such issue then you're welcome to respond.  :-)